# Passing Job Between Assembly Line Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

In an assembly line situation, how can I pass a job from thread1 to thread2 to thread3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic producer/consumer pattern. You need some sort of *blocking queue*. Two, in fact: one to pass jobs from thread 1 to thread 2, and one to pass from thread 2 to thread 3. The basic idea is that the *producer* thread posts jobs into the queue as soon as it has any, and the *consumer* requests jobs whenever it's ready. If the consumer requests a job before any are available, the request will block until something is ready.

This makes it dead easy to scale up later if you want more threads operating one part of your assembly line, or if you want to split one role into two.

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for the `BlockingQueue` interface.